# AWS API Gateway Locally

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I'm trying to build an api gateway for an app in development using aws. I followed the steps in the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-step-by-step.html.

However when I set my endpoint to be 127.0.0.1:3000/users for example, it returns an 500 {"message": "Internal server error"}.

The app is a simple nodejs endpoint run in docker. I'm just trying to discover api gateways.

I'm guessing the error is that the endpoint that I provide is not valid because I'm using it locally. So is there a way to use aws api gateway locally and is it the best option for an api gateway.

Comment: Enable CloudWatch logs with INFO level and do a test from the console. You might get more info on the error from the logs.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/

Answer (score 3):

The doc you mention doesn't describe any method for deploying and running an api gateway locally, nor am I aware of any method to do this. I'm only aware of running API Gateway in AWS. The problem may be that you are trying to hit an API Gateway endpoint on your local machine, which is not possible.

Perhaps I misunderstand and you're trying to integrate an API Gateway in AWS with a service running locally. If this is the case, API Gateway will not be able to have an integration endpoint on your local machine, unless you expose your machine to the public internet AND provide api gateway with a public internet address for your machine. 127.0.0.1 is not a public internet address.

Comment: Then how can we test (while developing) Angular App which consumes API Gateway as backend? any other alternate or what is the best practice?

Comment: i have asked this as separate question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68100445/we-have-anguler2-app-thinking-to-use-aws-api-gateway-as-backend-what-is-the-al