# We have Anguler2 App, thinking to use AWS API Gateway as Backend, What is the alternate for API Gateway while devlopment and testing locally

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, aws-api-gateway

We are developing an Angular App, and we need to use the Microservice Aggregation(AWS API Gateway) pattern.
But we need to consume the REST Services which are going to deploy in API Gateway, to test while developing.

We have Spring boot REST Services as microservices.